# Problema con codigo en C gon registros

Tags: c

```
#include "ipark.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void showParking(struct Parking parking_list) {
    
   
}

struct Parking registerEntry(struct Parking parking_list) {
    
    if (parking_list.available_slots == MAX_SLOTS){
        printf("Parking is full. Sorry.\n\n");
        printf("Nothing to show.");
    }
    else{
            printf ("Enter brand: ");
            scanf("%s", parking_list.slot_list[parking_list.available_slots].brand);
            printf ("Enter model: ");
            scanf("%s", parking_list.slot_list[parking_list.available_slots].model);
            printf ("Enter plate: ");
            scanf("%s", parking_list.slot_list[parking_list.available_slots].plate);
            parking_list.slot_list[parking_list.available_slots].available++;
        }
        

    return parking_list;
}

struct Parking registerExit(struct Parking parking_list) {
    int eleccion;
    
    if (parking_list.available_slots == 0){
        printf("Parking is empty. Exit registration not allowed.\n\n");
        printf("Nothing to show.");
    }
    else{
        showParking(parking_list);
        printf("Enter the slot number: ");
        scanf("%d", &eleccion);
        if(strcmp(parking_list.slot_list[eleccion].plate, "Empty.") == 1){
            strcmp(parking_list.slot_list[eleccion].plate, "Empty");
        }
        
    }
        
    

    return parking_list;

}

int main () {
    
    int num;
    char eleccion;
    struct Parking parking_list;
    
    printf("How many cars? ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    
    

    parking_list = initializeParking(parking_list, num);
    
    do{
        printf("Do you want to register an entry (n) or an exit (x)?");
        scanf ("%c", &eleccion);
    }while (eleccion != 'n' && eleccion != 'x');
    
    if (eleccion == 'n'){
       parking_list = registerEntry(parking_list);
    }
    
    
    if (eleccion == 'x'){
       parking_list = registerExit(parking_list);
    }
    
    showParking(parking_list);

    return 0;
}
```

donde ipark tiene esto:

```
#define MAX_CHARS 20
#define PLATE_CHARS 8
#define MAX_SLOTS 15

struct Slot {
    int slot_number;
    int available;
    char brand[MAX_CHARS];
    char model[MAX_CHARS];
    char plate[PLATE_CHARS];
};

struct Parking {
    int available_slots;
    struct Slot slot_list[MAX_SLOTS];
};
```

No estoy seguro si tengo algo bien en registerEntry ni en registerExit (initialitizeParking no nos lo dan).

Es un programa que pide cuantos carros hay en el parquedero y si queremos sacar o parquear otro carro.

ej.

```
How many cars? 0

Do you want to register an entry (n) or an exit (x)? n

Enter brand: seat
Enter model: tarraco
Enter plate: 1234abc

Parking slot #1: 1234abc.
Parking slot #2: Empty.
Parking slot #3: Empty.
Parking slot #4: Empty.
Parking slot #5: Empty.
Parking slot #6: Empty.
Parking slot #7: Empty.
Parking slot #8: Empty.
Parking slot #9: Empty.
Parking slot #10: Empty.
Parking slot #11: Empty.
Parking slot #12: Empty.
Parking slot #13: Empty.
Parking slot #14: Empty.
Parking slot #15: Empty.

ej2.
How many cars? 2

Do you want to register an entry (n) or an exit (x)? x

Parking slot #1: 5346CWD.
Parking slot #2: 1234JEX.
Parking slot #3: Empty.
Parking slot #4: Empty.
Parking slot #5: Empty.
Parking slot #6: Empty.
Parking slot #7: Empty.
Parking slot #8: Empty.
Parking slot #9: Empty.
Parking slot #10: Empty.
Parking slot #11: Empty.
Parking slot #12: Empty.
Parking slot #13: Empty.
Parking slot #14: Empty.
Parking slot #15: Empty.

Enter the slot number: 1

Parking slot #1: Empty.
Parking slot #2: 1234JEX.
Parking slot #3: Empty.
Parking slot #4: Empty.
Parking slot #5: Empty.
Parking slot #6: Empty.
Parking slot #7: Empty.
Parking slot #8: Empty.
Parking slot #9: Empty.
Parking slot #10: Empty.
Parking slot #11: Empty.
Parking slot #12: Empty.
Parking slot #13: Empty.
Parking slot #14: Empty.
Parking slot #15: Empty.
```

Comment: Pones el código y un par de ejemplos, pero no aclaras cuál es el problema. ¿Qué es lo que pasa? Los ejemplos ¿son de como funciona el programa o de como debería funcionar? ¿Cómo funciona en realidad tu programa?

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que esto:

```
parking_list.slot_list[parking_list.available_slots].available++;
```

debería ser realmente:

```
// La plaza actual deja de estar disponible
parking_list.slot_list[parking_list.available_slots].available = 0;

// Actualizamos el índice
parking_list.available_slots++;
```

En cualquier caso, llamar `available_slots` a una variable que realmente mide el número de registros ocupados me parece como menos que una aberración.

Por otro lado, date cuenta que este diseño te obliga a agrupar todas las plazas ocupadas al inicio de la lista. Es decir, si tienes 4 plazas ocupadas y se libera la primera, te tocará desplazar las 3 siguientes al inicio de la lista ... un engorro.

Entonces, ¿Cómo hacemos esto?

Lo suyo sería iterar sobre la lista de plazas en busca de alguna que tuviese la variable `available` a 1:

```
struct Slot * slot = NULL;
for( int i=0; i<MAX_SLOTS; i++ )
{
  struct Slot * slot = &parking_list.slot_list[i];
  if( parking_list.slot_list[i].available == 1 )
  {
    slot = &parking_list.slot_list[i];
    break;
  }
}

if( slot == NULL )
{
  printf("Parking is full. Sorry.\n\n");
  printf("Nothing to show.");
}
else
{
  // Ocupamos esta plaza
  slot->available = 0;
     
  printf ("Enter brand: ");
  scanf("%s", slot->brand);
  printf ("Enter model: ");
  scanf("%s", slot->model);
  printf ("Enter plate: ");
  scanf("%s", slot->plate);
}
```

Para liberar una plaza, ahora simplemente basta con poner el flag `available` a 1:

```
printf("Enter the slot number: ");
scanf("%d", &eleccion);
parking_list.slot_list[eleccion].available = 1;
```

Tras esto deberías actualizar también:

- La función que lista las plazas para que muestre como libres todas las que tengan `available==1`
- La inicialización. Debes poner a `available=1` en todas las plazas